# Modify automatically an attribute with magento

Tags: attributes, magento, entity-attribute-value

I want to modify one attribute of my product automatically (code). How could i do that plz?

I have seen how to show one attribute, but not how to modify.

Thx

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise? Are you trying to create and modify attributes on the fly? Would have already created attributes and then try to modify them? Is the attribute a text box, area, drop down, or what type? Could you detail the purpose. Attributes in Magento is a vast subject and somethings are possible while some are not.

Answer (score 1):

if attribute name is "attr" and product is loaded into object $product

```
$product->setAttr($value);
$product->save();
```