# Magento save attribute value programmatically causes SQL error

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

Could somebody please help?

In Magento 1.5.0.1 I am trying to save an attribute value for configurable product. I added my attribute to corresponding products using Admin.

I looked at [Modify automatically an attribute with magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819141/modify-automatically-an-attribute-with-magento) and [Programmatically change product attribute at store view level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614700/programmatically-change-product-attribute-at-store-view-level), so was able to come up with seemingly simple code which works unfortunately only sometimes - namely for configurable products without tier prices...

Here is a snippet of code:

```
$id = 126;  # id of existing product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 
$product->setx_pos(123);
// tried this too, does not make a difference:  $product->setData('x_pos',  123);
$product->save();
```

It works perfectly IF configurable product does not have products with tier prices. It can have tier products without tier prices, it this case save works. If tier products have tier prices – than I am getting the exception:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '126-1-0-5.0000-0' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_TIER_PRICE'
Trace:
#0 C:\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php(1513):        Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterSa...', Array)
#1 C:\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Product.php(142): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#2 C:\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php(1013):    Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product->_afterSave(Object  (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#3 C:\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(318):  Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#4 C:\magento\app\design\frontend\default\OneOffFit\template\page\data.phtml(90):  Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
```

I Googled on this error - the only refrence is unanswered question.

Why is Magento updating tier prices in this case? Am I doing anything wrong? Should I update associated products first (they have same attribute but with unset value)? Or rather what should I do right? Could anybody help please?

Comment: The conventional way to write setters in Magento is in camel case, for "x_pos" it should be `setXPos(123)`. This pedantry doesn't answer your question but it might help future developers who inspect your code.

Answer (score 3):

Move this line above the load command;

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Or if you're not concerned with store-specific values remove it altogether.

Comment: thanks a lot! This moving setCurrentStore up fixed my problem somehow. At this point I do not care about multiple stores, but I believe I saw the code either on StackOverflow or in Magento how to deal with multiple stores. Could you give a hint why this helped - I'd like to understand more about what was happening. Thanks again, VladJ

Comment: The problem key `UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_TIER_PRICE` is defined in the table `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`, it is an index of several columns including `website_id`. When you change the current store in between loading and saving an object it is treated as a new, alternative version of the object... But the `website_id` doesn't seem to be updated to match, so it conflicts with the existing version which is a violation of the aforementioned unique key. It's not intuitive and probably a bug albeit one that is easy to work around. I think of it as "doing something unexpected causes crashes".

Answer (score 1):

in my case when I put following code just above the product  load, the error is gone but browser is taking so long time to stop. Finally the attribute is also not updated.

Any idea what is happening to the code?

```
$productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('68366');
$product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$product->setMyAttribute('test')
    ->save();
```

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have the same problem, setting custom attribute value and then save() does not update the value.